# MVC numeric validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, numeric

I can't seem to ding a way to override the default behaviour of the MVC validation for numeric fields.

I've created a default MVC4 project to represent my problem.

The model (The default MVC 4 constructs for you, plus two properties "Age" and "Date"):

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
```

So by default MVC validates the two fields I've created and I'm getting the following validation messages: "The field "Age" is required" and "The field "Date" is required"

Now what i am trying to achieve is forcing my application to ignore the default numeric validation (I'm doing this on client side and it's impossible for a user to enter an invalid value). I have tried forcing MVC not to add default "required" attributes for non-nullable properties:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

This gave me some progress. Now it does not do "Required" validation, but posting of a form results two identical validation messages: "A value is required".

I could not achieve anything beyond this point. I've tried removing the ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider

```
        foreach (ModelValidatorProvider prov in ModelValidatorProviders.Providers)
        {
            if (prov.GetType().Equals(typeof(ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider)))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

as well as all providers altogether

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
```

without any success.

I've also tried to overload some of the default attributes MVC is using in DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider, however this gave me no results.

So there is a couple of question I'd like to ask about this situation:

1. Is it possible to force MVC not to do default validation on server side for non-nullable data types? If possible how?
2. Is it possible to change the default behaviour of validation described in the question no.1? If possible - how?
3. Is it possible to force MVC to use my custom validator / validation attribute instead of this custom one? If possible - how?

Also a note: I do *not* want to write my attribute that does validation for me and put it on every single property it should do validation on. I am looking for a solution, which would allow me to define the rules on how the default validation should be done.

Thanks in advance or any suggestions.

Comment: Make the Date and Age as nullable datetime and int respectively

Comment: I don't want to do that for a number of reasons. Data types have to be not nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own ModelBinder for `int`. Then make that binder return 0 on error.

```
public class IntModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToInt32(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            //Uncomment for default error
            //modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            actualValue = 0;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

And in Global.asax `Application_Start()`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(int), new IntModelBinder());
```